# Complexity (prove or disprove): If $f(g(n))=O(n)$ and $f(n)=Ω(n)$ then $g(n)=O(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I was wondering if I could get a hint on the following question (prove or disprove):

> If $f(g(n))=O(n) $ and $f(n)=Ω(n)$ then $g(n)=O(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition:$$
f(m) = {\mit Ω}(m) \Longleftrightarrow f(m) \geqslant cm, \quad \forall m \geqslant m_0
$$
where $c > 0$ is a constant and $m_0 \in \mathbb{N}_+$, and$$
f(g(n)) = O(n) \Longleftrightarrow f(g(n)) \leqslant Cn, \quad \forall n \geqslant n_0
$$
where $C > 0$ is a constant and $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}_+$.

In fact, assume that $f:\mathbb{N}_+ \to \mathbb{N}_+$ and$$
f(m) = {\mit Ω}(m) \Longleftrightarrow f(m) \geqslant cm. \quad \forall m \geqslant m_0
$$
Define$$
a = \min_{1 \leqslant m \leqslant m_0} f(n) > 0, \quad c' = \min(c, a),
$$
then$$
f(m) \geqslant c'm. \quad \forall m \geqslant 1
$$
Also assume that $g:\mathbb{N}_+ \to \mathbb{N}_+$, then$$
Cn \geqslant f(g(n)) \geqslant c'g(n).
$$

Comment: Isn't the this definition: $$
f(m) = {\mit Ω}(m) \Longleftrightarrow cm \leqslant f(m) \leqslant Cm, \quad \forall m \geqslant 1
$$
of $\Theta (n)$ , and not omega?

Comment: Yes , you wrote the definition I'm using now. I tried to write them out too, and defined $n=max[m_0,n_0]$. and tried to work it out from there, but got stuck.

Comment: f(m)⩾cm and, f(g(n))⩽C′n for n⩾1.
 I understand, but can I replace m with g(n) here?

Comment: That's the thing I'm struggling to understand, can you please explain why I can replace m with g(n) :) ?
If I understand that , I see how to finish the question.

Comment: $$
a = \min_{1 \leqslant m \leqslant m_0} f(n)$$
$m_0=1$ so isn't $a=f(1)$?
and on the last row , isn't it supposed to be Cn⩾f(g(n))⩾c'g(n).

Answer (score 0):

The question seems too fishy to be true.

Take $f(n) = \frac{1}{n} = \Omega(n)$ and $g(n) = n^2$, then $f(g(n)) = n = O(n)$, but the conclusion does not hold.

Comment: $$f(n)=1/n=Ω(n)$$ I don't think that this statement holds

Comment: So i misread the definition. :-(

Comment: it's ok :) thank you for helping!